# É legal fazer 'delete this' em uma função membro?

Tags: c++, c++11, advogado-de-linguagem

O idioma `delete this` serve para um objeto cometer suicídio. Por exemplo:

```
void Recurso::release() {
    --refs;
    if (refs == 0)
        delete this;

    // Aqui o 'this' pode ser um ponteiro inválido,
    // tocar o objeto por qualquer meio seria errado.
}
```

O que ocorre aqui é que a função foi chamada em um objeto válido e a vida do objeto se encerrou **durante** a execução da função. É permitido e legal que a vida de um objeto se encerre enquanto uma função membro se encontra em execução?

Esse outro caso mostra uma chamada em um objeto inválido (nessa memória não se encontra um `MyObj` dentro do seu período de vida).

```
void MyObj::noop() {
    // Não vou tocar no 'this' aqui!
}

MyObj* obj = (MyObj*)0xDEADBEEF;
obj->noop();
```

Esse código é válido? Se não é, por que o `delete this` seria válido já que o resultado é efetivamente o mesmo?

Um outro exemplo:

```
MyObj* obj;

void destroyObj() { delete obj; }
void MyObj::func() { destroyObj(); }

int main() { obj = new MyObj; obj->func(); }
```

Embora não ocorra um `delete this`, o exemplo é similar no sentido de que o objeto é destruído dentro de `func()`.

Sendo ou não um objeto polimórfico, isso é permitido?

Para qualquer implementação real, isso não é problema desde que o objeto não seja acessado após a destruição. Mas pode haver um *undefined behaviour* se escondendo aqui.

**Aos olhos do standard, pode?** (de preferência prove com trechos do mesmo)

<sub>Não quero entrar no mérito de se isso é ou não uma boa prática. (não é!)</sub>

Comment: Pergunta muito interessante, ficarei de olho para ver a resposta. Se é válido ou não eu não sei, só sei que executa como esperado. :)

Comment: Sem definir que `MyObj` é ou não polimórfico, não é possível dizer se `this` será acessado na chamada de um de seus métodos. Não é possível dizer se `noop` é virtual pois não é possível ver a declaração de `MyObj` e se esta herda ou não o método como virtual.

Comment: @pepper_chico, Eu entendo que na prática vai funcionar se nao for polimórfico, mas é realmente legal aos olhos do standard? Assuma que não é uma função virtual se preferir. Isso faz chamar uma função membro em um objeto inválido ser permitido? É esse detalhe que faz a diferença.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Entendo, meu ponto é reformular a questão pra que fique explicito o que você quer, no momento só lendo o resto dos comentários pra entender onde você quer chegar. Excluindo essas ambiguidades ajudaria a questão em si.

Comment: IMO, a referência por C. E. Gesser do padrão parece suficiente pra sanar a questão se você for pedante, digo se você seguir ao pé da letra o que é dito, ela está cobrindo o caso. O padrão diz exatamente, **se você chamar** é UB, como pode ser visto aqui, o seu primeiro caso **não chama**, independente de onde esteja a execução no momento, não haverá nenhuma chamada para métodos de objetos inválidos, no segundo caso, sim.

Comment: @pepper A resposta dele cobre o segundo caso e me prova que é de fato inválido. Mas nada me garante sobre o caso do delete this, como afirmei em um comentário. Reformularei a questão assim que possível.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal o que tentei dizer é que garante sim, se você seguir o paragrafo ao pé da letra, no momento do `delete this` em diante não há nenhuma chamada a método para objeto inválido, e quando houve a ultima chamada, ele era de fato válido. O paragrafo explica sobre chamadas em objetos inválidos e que estas são UB, se não, não. Por isso me refiro, "independente do ponto de execução".

Comment: O que diferencia o ponto de execução estar dentro ou fora de uma função qualquer? Acho difícil o padrão se referir a tais contextos nestes casos.

Comment: @pepper_chico fiz a edição, deve estar um pouco mais claro agora a minha intenção. Obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal apesar de a gente saber que roda, o segundo caso já não deveria ser descartado? por que o trecho do padrão por Gesser já implica que isto se enquadra em UB.

Comment: @pepper Se eu remover da pergunta vou tornar a resposta dele descontextualizada e sem sentido. Não posso fazer isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal ah ok, acho bom fazer um edit de quê já é assumido como UB então segundo a resposta, do contrário acharão que é algo permitido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sim, é legal (para objetos criados com `new`)

Para os fins desta resposta, estou utilizando o mesmo [rascunho](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) utilizado [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6251/114377). É um rascunho um pouco antigo, mas a pergunta é sobre [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), afinal.

### A expressão `delete this` é legal?

Para avaliarmos a legalidade da expressão `delete this`, primeiro devemos saber o que exatamente é a expressão `this`.

> **[class.this] / 1**
>
> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose **value is the address of the object for which the function is called**. The type of `this` in a member function of a class `X` is `X*`. If the member function is declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`, if the member function is declared `volatile`, the type of `this` is `volatile X*`, and if the member function is declared `const volatile`, the type of `this` is `const volatile X*`.

*(Ênfase minha)*

Ou seja, para uma classe `T`, e assumindo uma função-membro sem especificadores `const` ou `volatile`, `this` é uma expressão com tipo `T*` e valor igual ao endereço do objeto no qual foi chamada a função.

Então, devemos saber quais expressões são válidas como operandos do operador `delete`.

> **[expr.delete] / 2**
>
> If the operand has a class type, the operand is converted to a pointer type by calling the above-mentioned conversion function, and the converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the remainder of this section. In the first alternative (*delete object*), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, **a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous `new-expression`, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.** In the second alternative (*delete array*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array `new-expression`. If not, the behavior is undefined.

*(Ênfase minha)*

Sabemos que para um tipo `X`, `this` tem tipo `X*`. Ou seja, `this` **é** um ponteiro para um objeto, e esse objeto não é uma array. **Esse ponteiro é válido como operando da expressão `delete` se, e somente se, o objeto em questão foi criado com `new`.** Caso contrário, o comportamento é indefinido.

Assumindo então que nosso objeto foi criado com `new`, E utilizando os trechos acima, já estabelecemos que, por si só, a expressão `delete this` é legal.

### Se `delete this` é legal, o que acontece com a função em execução?

Para estabelecermos o que acontece então, devemos saber exatamente o que a expressão `delete obj` faz.

> **[expr.delete] / 7**
>
> If the value of the operand of the `delete-expression` is not a null pointer value, the `delete-expression` will call a `deallocation function` (3.7.4.2). Otherwise, it is unspecified whether the deallocation function will be called.

e

> **[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation] / 4**
>
> If the argument given to a deallocation function in the standard library is a pointer that is not the null pointer value (4.10), **the deallocation function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer, rendering invalid
>   all pointers referring to any part of the *deallocated storage***. Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.

*(Ênfase minha)*

Note que tudo o que acontece (excetuando-se qualquer lógica dentro do destrutor) é uma desalocação de memória. Sim, o ponteiro `this` é invalidado. Resta saber se, ao retornar, a função dereferencia `this` de alguma forma.

> ### 6.6.3  The return statement
>
> **[stmt.return]**
>
> **1** A function returns to its caller by the return statement.
>
> **2** A return statement with neither an *expression* nor a *braced-init-list* can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type `void`, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4). A return statement with an expression of non-void type can be used only in functions returning a value; the value of the expression is returned to the caller of the function. The value of the expression is implicitly converted to the return type of the function in which it appears.  A return statement can involve the construction and copy or move of a temporary object (12.2). *[Note:*
>   A copy or move operation associated with a return statement may be elided or considered as an rvalue for the purpose of overload resolution in selecting a constructor (12.8). *— end note]* A return statement with a *braced-init-list* initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer list. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> std::pair<std::string,int> f(const char* p, int x) {
>     return {p,x};
> }
> ```
>
> *— end example]*
>
> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.
>
> **3** A return statement with an expression of type `void` can be used only in functions with a return type of *cv* `void`; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller.

O padrão não fala nada sobre dereferenciamento de ponteiros no retorno de funções. Por que falaria? Lendo a sua questão, posso ver que você mesmo sabe que implementações não precisam dereferenciar o ponteiro `this` ao retornar de uma função membro. Tudo o que é necessário é um endereço de retorno. Infelizmente a única forma de "provar" esta afirmação é citando toda a seção sobre retorno de funções. Felizmente, não é uma seção muito grande :D.

### Se retornar após executar `delete this` (E invalidar o ponteiro `this`) não causa comportamento indefinido, chamar uma função que não faz nada (só retorna) em um ponteiro inválido é legal?

*É, esse título poderia ter ficado um pouco menor...*

Essa seção lida especialmente com este trecho da questão:

```
void MyObj::noop() {
    // Não vou tocar no 'this' aqui!
}

MyObj* obj = (MyObj*)0xDEADBEEF;
obj->noop();
```

Esse código causa comportamento indefinido, pois estamos dereferenciando um ponteiro provavelmente inválido. Consegue adivinhar onde?

```
obj->noop()
```

A expressão acima tem efeito equivalente à expressão:

```
(*obj).noop()
```

Que claramente dereferencia o ponteiro `obj`, causando comportamento indefinido.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78044/discussion-between-mario-feroldi-and-cassio-renan).

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com [este *draft*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) do *standard*, seção 9.3.1 (*Nonstatic member functions*), item 2:

> If a non-static member function of a class X is called for an object
>   that is not of type X, or of a type derived from X, the behavior is
>   undeﬁned.

Ou seja, chamar um função membro não-estática de uma classe `X` sobre um objeto que não é da classe `X` (ou derivadas) resulta em comportamento não definido. Não há exceção para funções que não acessem `this` ou qualquer variável ou função membro.

No primeiro caso, após o `delete`, `this` continua apontando para onde **havia** um objeto válido, mas a memória já foi retornada para o *pool* do sistema. Portanto não é garantido que haja ali um objeto válido. Pelo meu entendimento, isto se encaixaria nessa regra caso alguma função membro fosse chamada **após** o `delete`, mesmo que fosse uma função que não acessasse os membros.

Já no segundo caso, claramente o endereço inválido não aponta para um objeto da classe especificada, então não é objeto válido. Cai na regra do comportamento não definido.

Mas na prática, tudo isso vai funcionar porque não se lê nada de endereços inválidos.

Resposta inspirada/adaptada desta [pergunta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha).

Comment: O que me causa dúvida é: "If a non-static member function of a class X **is called**...". No caso do `delete this`, a função **foi** chamada em um objeto válido do tipo certo, mas este ficou inválido durante a execução da função. Acha que também cobre esse caso?

Comment: Eu acho que teria problema se você chamasse outra função após o `delete`. Editei a resposta para esclarecer o ponto.

Answer (score 0):

Não acredito que seja uma boa prática, pois dependendo da implementação podem ocorrer sérios problemas.
Verifique mais detalhes em [[ 16.14 ] É legal, e moral, uma função membro comandar delete this ?](http://www.arnaut.eti.br/op/CPPFL16.htm#%5b16.14%5d)
ou na versão em inglês [[16.15] Is it legal (and moral) for a member function to say delete this?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/delete-this.html)

Comment: Dependendo da implementação? Então não é um comportamento definido pelo standard? O link faz afirmações (já conhecidas) sem nenhuma base, que não é o que estou buscando.

Comment: Guilherme Bernal o link referido é uma base de conhecimento muito séria e contém recomendações valiosas.

Comment: Não estou a questionar a validade do link, concordo com tudo que está ali. Meu ponto é que não há provas do que está sendo dito lá e é esse meu objetivo com a pergunta. Ter uma referência sólida e oriunda do próprio standard.

Answer (score 0):

É válido, assim como é válido chamar o próprio destructor (obj->~Classe()), mas o programador tem enorme responsabilidade em saber o que está fazendo, que o 'this' não será utilizado em seguida etc. Para o seu caso, usar smart pointer seria muito melhor.

Comment: Fazer `obj->~Classe()` sem dúvida é válido. Mas fazer `this->~Classe()`  é também? Não sei. O problema pode ser escrito como: "Posso terminar a vida de um objeto dentro de um membro dele?"

Comment: Deve ser algo usado dentro da STL e olhe lá

Comment: Cada implementação da stdlib usa um monte de recursos que são específicos do compilador para o qual foram projetadas. Não são totalmente portáveis e por isso não seriam uma boa fonte nesse caso.

Answer (score 0):

Comparando os dois casos, há uma diferença que no segundo a execução do código ainda envolve a realização da chamada para a função membro, e no primeiro isso já ocorreu.

Sem verificar as limitações ditadas pelo padrão, já vejo esta diferença como crucial pois, apesar do segundo caso funcionar para objetos de classes não polimórficas, para objetos de classes polimórficas seria claramente UB pois para chamar o metódo é necessário acesso à vtable que é um dado dentro de um objeto válido. No caso de quando já ocorreu a chamada do método, e o objeto não mais será acessado, se o objeto é polimófico ou não, não interferiria.

Outra coisa relacionada ao primeiro caso é que, você assegura que este método somente será chamado para `this` de objetos do *free storage* (a.k.a. *heap*)? Por que `delete` em ponteiros para objetos de *automatic storage* (a.k.a. *stack*) já não seria algo válido.

Baseado nisso e nos comentários deixados em outras respostas, talvez uma minuciosa reformulação da pergunta seria uma boa sugestão.